# How to pass View visibility state between Activities

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

hey guys how to use sharedpreferences in my project. I have a floating button in my mainactivity and secondactivity when i click the floating button the compass will be disabled then when i go in the secondactivity the compass is enabled which is disabled instead.How to resolve this problem?

here is my code baseactivity

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



    FloatingActionButton compass1 = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.comp);
    compass1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout1).getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE){
                findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Compass Has Been Disabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            else{

                findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Compass Has Been Enabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);



}
```

@Override
 public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

```
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_first) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(myIntent);
        finish();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_second) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this,SecondFloor.class);
        myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(myIntent);
        finish();



    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `SharedPreferences` for that. Just pass an Intent extra that has the visibility state of the compass.

Save the state from the compass1 click listener in a class field `isCompassVisible`

When creating the intent for `SecondFloor` do:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this,SecondFloor.class);
myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
myIntent.putExtra("isCompassVisible", isCompassVisible);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

In `SecondFloor` Activity's `onCreate` (or wherever you need it):

```
if(getIntent().hasExtra("isComapssVisible")
    comapssView.setVisibility(getIntent().getBooleanExtra("isCompassVisible", true) ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
```

Comment: I dont know how to this "Save the state from the compass1 click listener in a class field isCompassVisible". Sorry, im newbie in android

Comment: `isCompassVisible = findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout1).getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE ? false : true;`

Answer (score 0):

1.You can use Shared preferences to set the value as:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Values.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putBoolean("isShowing", true/false);
editor.apply();
```

and get it as:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = ((Activity)context).getSharedPreferences("TAG", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Boolean shown = prefs.getBoolean("isShowing",true);
```

2. But you would be better of passing the boolean value in your intent.

simply pass it with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putBoolean("isShowing",true/false);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

and get it:

```
Boolean b = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("isShowing",false);
```

3. Optionally, you could also use a public static boolean variable in either activity or a utils folder which will be accessible to you from either activity.

Comment: There is no need of creating the `Bundle` object, but other than that you're right.